# Cisco RV110W log file shows System Error & Kernel Warning

Tags: cisco, router

The log from my Cisco RV110W router shows the following errors and warnings:

```
2013-01-14 18:17:10 RV110W syslog.err syslog-ng[20712]: 
Connection broken to AF_INET(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx), reopening in 60 seconds

2013-01-14 18:18:11 RV110W syslog.err syslog-ng[20712]: 
Connection broken to AF_INET(xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx), reopening in 60 seconds

2013-01-14 18:19:11 RV110W syslog.err syslog-ng[20712]: 
Connection broken to AF_INET(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx), reopening in 60 seconds

2013-01-14 18:19:22 RV110W kern.warning nf_ct_ras: decoding error: out of range
```

I posted this question in the Cisco support community but after several days I still not received any reply.

Does anyone know what these messages mean and what I can do to stop receiving them?